# Import flow types from react-native

Tags: react-native, flowtype

I am trying to use flow in my current react-native project. After some research, I discovered that all the types I need are in [this file](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/26684cf3adf4094eb6c405d345a75bf8c7c0bf88/Libraries/Components/View/ViewPropTypes.js#L32-L43), but I have no idea how I am supposed to import these types.

For instance, I need to import the `ViewLayoutEvent` from there. What am I supposed to write in my file?

I tried the following:

```
import type { ViewLayoutEvent } from 'react-native';
import type { ViewLayoutEvent } from 'react-native/Libraries/Components/View/ViewPropTypes';
```

To no avail.

**Update:**

Or maybe it is in [this file](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/26684cf3adf4094eb6c405d345a75bf8c7c0bf88/Libraries/Types/CoreEventTypes.js)